# How to configure my XCFramework to allow Modularization

Tags: xcode, static-libraries, libraries, xcframework, modularization

The scenario is the following:
I have an Xcode Workspace with two different Framework projects: Alpha and Beta.
Both Frameworks have `Mach-O Type` equal to `Static Library`.

Alpha is dependent on Beta.
Beta is independent.

While creating the binaries for both libraries, Beta always succeeds in the archive process, but Alpha always fails.

```
xcodebuild archive \
-scheme FrameworkNameHere \
-configuration Release \
-destination 'generic/platform=iOS' \
-archivePath './build/FrameworkNameHere.framework-iphoneos.xcarchive' \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
```

The error message that I get when trying to create the Alpha archive using the above code (changing "FrameworkNameHere" for "Alpha") is:

```
The following build commands failed:
    SwiftCompile normal arm64 /Users/myname/iOS-Projects/ThePathToTheFolder/Alpha/SomeAlphaFileThatImportsBeta.swift (in target 'Alpha' from project 'Alpha')
    SwiftCompile normal arm64 Compiling\ SomeAlphaFileThatImportsBeta.swift /Users/myname/iOS-Projects/ThePathToTheFolder/Alpha/SomeAlphaFileThatImportsBeta.swift (in target 'Alpha' from project 'Alpha')
```

The file that fails is a file where I use `import Beta`.

Am I trying to do something that is not possible?

How can I create a binary for Alpha?